# C# Exception on creating a instance of a object of a Erwind DLL

Tags: c#, exception, erwin

// I must to create a program that run by a DLL library of the //Software Erwin.
  //  I imported the DLL the project and this is the code :

//  The exception is : `Error 80040154 unregistered interface`

//   What' s wrong ? How I can do that ?

//    This is the full code :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace Prova1
{

    class MainClass
    {


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SCAPI.Application scApp = new SCAPI.Application();//Exception

                if (scApp == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Erwin API could not be started.");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" Hello World!" + scApp.ApiVersion);
            }
            catch (Exception e){

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `using` statements?...

Comment: Did you add that DLL in Reference?

Comment: Yes . I Added it!

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

 
namespace Prova1
{
     
    class MainClass
    {
         
         
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SCAPI.Application scApp = new SCAPI.Application();